# Is there a python function for cumulative probability

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Id   Day1   Day2   Day3 
1    0.35   0.32   0.29  
2    0.63   0.59   0.58
3    0.12   0.10   0.07
```

This table shows the probability of a certain event occurring on each day, for each record.

What I'm searching for is a python function that will give me the cumulative probability of the event occurring on **any** day. The output would look like this:

```
Id   Day1   Day2   Day3  Cum_Prob
1    0.35   0.32   0.29  0.686
2    0.63   0.59   0.58  0.983
3    0.12   0.10   0.07  0.263
```

The `Cum_Prob` values in the above sample table are correct i.e. they are the actual probability of the event occurring on any of the 3 days for each `Id` value.

I can write this function myself for a couple of days. In reality, I'm dealing with a lot more than 3 days, and I believe hand-writing this function for lots of days will be extremely tedious.

Is there a pre-existing function that can calculate probability from an input of individual probabilities? Or is there a quick way to write a udf for this over x number of days?

Comment: Why isn't the cumulative probability not adding up to the result you've provided?

Comment: Perhaps I have not been clear in my question, but what I need is the probability that the event will happen on any day. Just taking the sum of the values for each Id does not make sense. For example, that would yield a `cum_prob` value of > 1 for `Id=2`, which makes no sense. I've updated the wording of my question to hopefully clarify

Comment: Did you look through the Pandas documentation? did you try to craft your own?

Comment: What is the *equation* for three days?

Comment: define your logic, so it just seems the sum and this is

Comment: Here is the mathematical explanation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234474/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-an-event-occuring-within-n-days-if-we-know

Comment: In the above question, the probability for each day is the same, so the resulting equation is much simpler than it would be with different values for each day

Comment: ... then how would you write the equation for your situation?

Comment: There isn't a method for this in pandas, please check my EDIT answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little math, this is just

```
1 - (1-df).prod(1)
# if your `Id` is not index:
# 1 - df.filter(like='days)
# 1 - df.set_index('Id')
```

Output:

```
Id
1    0.686180
2    0.936286
3    0.263440
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df['Cum_Prob'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
```

or

```
df['Cum_Prob'] = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Day')]].sum(axis=1)
```

**EDIT**

```
df_days = df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Day')]]
cumprob=0
for i, col in df_days.items():
    cumprob = col.mul(1-cumprob) + cumprob
```

---

```
df['Cum_Prob']=cum_Prob
```

**Output**

```
   Id  Day1  Day2  Day3  Cum_Prob
0   1  0.35  0.32  0.29  0.686180
1   2  0.63  0.59  0.58  0.936286
2   3  0.12  0.10  0.07  0.263440
```

Alternative with **reduce**

```
from functools import reduce
df['Cum_Prob']=reduce(lambda cum_prob, new_prob: (1-cum_prob)*new_prob + cum_prob ,
                      df_days.values.T)
```

---

**reduce may be the fastest**

```
%%timeit
from functools import reduce
df['Cum_Prob']=reduce(lambda cum_prob, new_prob: (1-cum_prob)*new_prob + cum_prob ,
                      df_days.values.T)
111 µs ± 2.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

```
%%timeit
cumprob=0
for i, col in df_days.items():
    cumprob = col.mul(1-cumprob) + cumprob
df['Cum_Prob']=cumprob
1.44 ms ± 5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is very close to being correct, thanks. With the following edit, I works as expected:

Comment: for i, col in df_days.items():
    cumprob = col.mul(1-cumprob) + cumprob

Comment: I am glad to help